# How to interactively subset columns from a data.frame in Shiny?

Tags: r, dataframe, shiny, subset

I want to create an interaction in shiny like database query.  \

1. create a text box for a list of gene IDs copy-pasted;
2. Alternatively, upload a file containing all the gene ID list;

In the `mainPanel()` I will get the subset of the dataframe by the gene IDs submitted. In R, this can be achieved as:

```
df[c("gene1", "gene2", "gene3", "gene4"),]
```

In shiny **ui.R** I have:

```
tabPanel("Browsing Gene(s)", tableOutput("queryTableCopy"), footer),
```

And **server.R** I have:

```
output$queryTable = renderTable ({
    if(is.null(values$data$mat)) return(NULL)
    df[c("XLOC_005722", "XLOC_001942", "XLOC_001107"), ]  #hardcoded
})
```

which is hard coded.

Just started shiny, but not sure how this should be implemented in shiny.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your editing of my post.
The edited title is not exactly my question. What I meant is "subset rows of the dataframe...".

Answer (score 0):

I think this does what you want. Adding a global.R is useful, so you can use the column names of your dataframe in the selectizeInput in the UI.

global.R

```
df_genes = data.frame(gene1=rep(1,10),gene2=rep(2,10),gene3=rep(3,10))
```

ui.R

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectizeInput("genes", "Select genes:", choices = colnames(df_genes),selected=colnames(df_genes),multiple=TRUE)
    ),
    mainPanel(
              DT::dataTableOutput("queryTable")
    )
  )
))
```

server.R

```
library(shiny)

shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  output$queryTable = DT::renderDataTable({
    if(length(input$genes)>0)
    {
      df = df_genes %>% select(input$genes)
      print(df)
      return(DT::datatable(df))
    }
    else
    {
      return(NULL)
    }
  })

})
```

I hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thanks Florian! 
What I mean is to add a function so that I can paste the geneIDs in the textAreaInput, or by upload a file containing the geneIDs.
So far in UI.R I have:
    conditionalPanel(condition = "input.tabs1 == 'Browsing Gene(s)'",
    h4("Export options"),
    textAreaInput("geneIDs", "Gene IDs of interest:",)
    ),
in server.R:
    output$queryTable = renderTable({
    mydf <- cutMatrix(values$data$mat)    #The whole table
    gene_list =  reactive({ unlist(strsplit(input$geneIDs, '[\r\n]')) })
    mydf[gene_list(),]
    })
Sorry, not familiar with markdown code!